# Ignite on YARN - IGNITE_RUN_CPU_PER_NODE not obeyed

Tags: hadoop-yarn, ignite

When I start the Ignite on Yarn application with one CPU per node it works as expected and launches containers, however when I try to start it with 8 cores per node, the containers in YARN launch and get killed immediately, leaving only the AM running.

These settings is what works:

```
IGNITE_RUN_CPU_PER_NODE=1
IGNITE_MEMORY_PER_NODE=122880
IGNITE_NODE_COUNT=3
```

These settings won't work:

```
IGNITE_RUN_CPU_PER_NODE=8
IGNITE_MEMORY_PER_NODE=122880
IGNITE_NODE_COUNT=3
```

I have also tried other numbers of CPUs per node but it will only work with 1.

How can I make this work? The logs are not existent for each of the containers launched and killed. I can only see from the YARN RM that they were allocated and released.

Comment: How many CPUs do you have on the servers?

Comment: 32 - 16 physical and 16 virtual. yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores is set to 32 and yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores is set to 1

Comment: Which yarn resource calculator should we be using?